# Qt version in centos7

Tags: c++, qt, centos7, qmake

I am using centos 7. To check the version of qt installed I am using the command `qmake --version` which returns

```
Qmake version: 1.07a (Qt 3.3.8b).
Qmake is free software from Trolltech ASA.
```

However when I give the command `yum install qt`, I get the message

```
Package 1:qt-4.8.5-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version.
Nothing to do.
```

I am not sure which version of qt is installed in my system! I need to have a qt version > 4.7.

Comment: you may have multiple versions. Perhaps the `qmake` on your path is symlink to a specific version. There may be a proper way to set a different one. I don't know much about Qt though, so I cant be sure.

Comment: Well it says qt-***4.8.5***-13.el7.x86_64 is installed. I'd assume that's v4.8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the file .bash_profile as 
`export QTDIR=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2 
export PATH=$QTDIR/bin:$PATH`
after removing qt3 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Qt is designed to support multiple parallel installations. I usually have dozens on my systems - multiple versions, targets, configurations.

It's on you to select the version of `qmake` that represents the Qt installation you're wishing to use. There's a 1:1 mapping between a `qmake` binary and a Qt installation.

To find all `qmake` binaries on your system, you can e.g. `$ locate qmake | grep bin`

The version of `qmake` present in your `PATH` is of no consequence, generally speaking, since for any given project you only need to invoke `qmake` directly once - you do so by giving the full path to the `qmake` in the install of Qt you're using in the build. Subsequent invocations are done via `make qmake_all`. I personally find no need for `qmake` in the `PATH` at all - it's too easy to run wrong one by mistake.

To recap, for any given project, you'd do:

```
set CPUS=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
mkdir build-projectFoo
cd build-projectFoo
/path/to/Qt/bin/qmake ../projectFoo-src
# no need to call qmake directly from this point onwards
make -j$CPUS
... (modifications to sources, project files, etc.)
make qmake_all && make -j$CPUS
```

Comment: @AMB You need to install it on your system then. It usually comes preinstalled in even minimal installs, but perhaps on your system it isn't. What distro do you have? On CentOS you'd install it via `yum install slocate` or `sudo you install slocate` depending on whether you use root user or the safer sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what Qt packages are installed with:
`# yum list qt*`

This will give you the list of Qt packages actually installed on your system (and the ones available for installation). Make sure you don't have any older qt package installed.

@tambre is right, qt-4.8.5-13.el7.x86_64 is Qt 4.8.5.

You can the also use: `$ whereis qmake`
to get the location of the `qmake` that is accessed via your $PATH (it will most likely be `/usr/bin/qmake`).

Then, check if the `qmake` actually installed by your package matches the previous result with: `# rpm -ql qt`

---

**Are you using CentOS as a workstation (with GUI) or as a server (without GUI) ?**

Because if, after the previous steps, you still get the wrong qmake, and you're using QtCreator in a  you can manually set a new "Qt Version" in QtCreator linked to the qmake you want (v4.8.5).

To do that, go to QtCreator > Tools > Options...; then Build & Run > Qt Versions tab.
Check if the Qt version you're looking for has already been detected automatically. If not, 
choose "Add" on the left, and navigate to the qmake of the wanted version.

Now check if a Kit exists for the Qt version you added (in the "Kits" tab) and if not, add a new kit linked to the Qt version you want, device type you need, etc.

You can then use this kit to configure existing projects and build then with it. To do so, go in the Projects tab in QtCreator (Ctrl+5) and select the wanted kit for your project.

D

Comment: I am using CentOS as a workstation.The command ` yum list qt*` returns "Error: No matching Packages to list", `whereis qmake` gives "qmake: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/qmake" and `rpm -ql qt` gives the list of several packages of qt-4.8.5

Comment: Ok. What packages are marked as installed with `rpm -ql qt`? Apparently you have qt-3.3 installed. If you don't need it, I would recommend remove it to avoid interference with qt-4.8.

Comment: "/usr/bin/qdbus
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.8.5
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4.8.5
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.5"
... and so on.Do I need to change the path of qmake?I mean I want `whereis qmake` command should return qt4 directory instead of qt3.3.How to change that?

Comment: Check the response. I just added further information to setup an additional Qt Version in Qt Creator

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my previous comment - you should see a whole bunch of packages with `yum list qt*` (execute as root), including qt, qt3 and qt5 packages (I just tested it on a CentOS install). Since you apparently have qt3 installed, you could also run `# yum remove qt3` to uninstall it

Comment: Oh and by the way, you can find the 4.8 qmake with this command: `$ rpm -ql qt | grep qmake`. So you will probably get something like /usr/lib64/qt-4.8/bin/qmake ?

Comment: That is very surprising... Well you can 1. try to uninstall qt3 as mentioned in my previous command, and 2. if that doesn't work, just add an additional Qt Version to Qt Creator by following the steps I described

Comment: I removed qt3,now on giving the `qmake` command it returns "bash: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/qmake: No such file or directory".Since qt4 is installed in my system how to change the path of qmake from its default path of qt3.3 to qt 4.8?

Comment: A reboot should be enough to refresh your PATH and give you the right qmake reference

Comment: I edited the file .bash_profile as `export QTDIR=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2
export PATH=$QTDIR/bin:$PATH` after removing qt3 and now its working fine.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. You should mark the correct answer as such. And if you don't consider my answer to be the best one, I'd appreciate an upvote nonetheless ;-) Thanks!