# After installing Qt 5.8 all qt applications stopped working

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5.5

everyone!

I have got a bit of a problem. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64. Apt provide only Qt 5.5.1 as the latest version, but I needed to install Qt above 5.6 (I have gone with Qt 5.8) because I needed to compile one of the in-house tools (which require Qt >=5.6).

But after installing Qt 5.8 (unfortunately, I used the installer, which was suggested on their website rather than compile it from git repository) I have done a strategic mistake. The system did not pick it up, but instead of setting an extra profile for qtchooser, I decided to copy all libraries to /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu, including changing all libQt5*.so.5 symbolic links. I do not know why did I do it... Possibly, I was drunk, or just too tired... But now I realise, that it was stupid.

After that I deinstalled Qt5.8 leaving the original Qt5.5.1 and Qt 4.8.7 (both installed through apt).

The problem is that after that all (at least, seems all) qt applications, that came from apt repository stopped working with the following error:

```
:~$ retext
Using configuration file: ~/.config/ReText project/ReText.conf
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the       Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tested retext, qbittorrent, vlc... And, obviously, I tried to reinstall each of these applications. It did not help me.

I have seen several questions and tutorials regarding specifically this type of errors, but most of them recommend to check library libqxcb.so in /path/to/qt/plugins/platforms/ and check whether it misses any dependencies. Restoring dependencies helped everybody. But not me. Here is list of dependencies:

```
:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms$ ldd libqxcb.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeb5fc4000)
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007f9c2aa62000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f9c2a51a000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f9c2a043000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9c29cc1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9c298f8000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f9c296f5000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f9c294e5000)
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007f9c292e1000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f9c290d8000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f9c28ebe000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f9c28cb4000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f9c28a91000)
    libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007f9c2888c000)
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007f9c28687000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f9c2847f000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f9c28277000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f9c28073000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007f9c27e64000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f9c27c60000)
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007f9c27a5d000)
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007f9c27841000)
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007f9c27639000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f9c273f6000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f9c2714b000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f9c26e3a000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f9c26b00000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f9c268c0000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007f9c26842000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9c26625000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9c2631b000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f9c260f6000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f9c25e97000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9c25c7d000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f9c259d9000)
    libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f9c25576000)
    libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f9c251e2000)
    libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007f9c24f7c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9c24d77000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9c24b6f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9c24959000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a753a16000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f9c24746000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f9c24541000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f9c2433c000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f9c24136000)
    libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007f9c23f30000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9c23d06000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9c23a96000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f9c23849000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f9c23624000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f9c233f3000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f9c23125000)
    libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f9c2166e000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f9c215e8000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9c213c6000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f9c211a3000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f9c20ec2000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f9c20cae000)
```

Then there were also recommendations to reinstall packages libQt5Gui5, which I also did, which did not help either.

Finally, I have found that libqxcb.so (which is in /path/to/qt/plugins/platforms/) uses its own paths and that libraries libQt5DBus.so.5 and libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 should be located in the same directory. Even though all the dependencies seems satisfied, I decided to try it as well. No luck again.

If anyone have any idea what else can be wrong and how this situation can be resolved, please, share it [idea]. I will really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Surprisingly, after I tried to remove and reinstall all libqt5 packages together with all libraries for xcb and several extra libraries, which Qt5 depends on, I came across this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without), which is very simple and elegant solution. And it worked perfectly fine. In any case, I would like to say thank you to all the contributors to this question for their time as it helped me a lot in understanding what should I do and (more importantly) don't do in such situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"how this situation can be resolved" Roll back to the LVM snapshot you took before you started messing with it?

I guess if you have to ask, you don't leverage LVM, so now you will know that it's not there to be a nuisance, but to prevent major breakage.

1. Ensure you have your filesystem on an LVM volume, and there's space left for snapshots. Most distributions hopefully set up LVM for you already, so if you have no space left you'll have to downsize the filesystem to free up some space. Otherwise, you'll have to convert your disks to LVM. Use the systemrescuecd, or any other good live distro, to do that.
2. Take a snapshot.
3. Forcibly remove the system Qt packages (all of them).
4. Forcibly reinstall the system Qt packages.
5. Verify that the system Qt applications now work.
6. Take a snapshot.
7. Reinstall Qt in your home folder.
8. Ensure everything still works and you can use your new Qt.
9. Drop snapshots if you wish to.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you learned an expensive lesson - `never manually replace Linux system libraries` :-)

So first of all, what you should have done is install the Qt library in your home directory, and added a new Qt kit to QtCreator linking to it. (Here's further info on how to add a custom Qt kit to QtCreator: [Qt version in centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716231/qt-version-in-centos7/43716875#43716875))

Now, here's what I would try to do to solve the issue :

1. Get the list of files belonging to the Qt5 package, and save it to a file: `$ dpkg -l qt5-5-1 > qt5_file_list.txt` (You should replace `qt5-5-1` with the exact name of the package)
2. Completely remove any system Qt5 library
3. Make sure there are no Qt5 files left (especially the symlinks you created manually)
4. Apply all the latest Ubuntu updates (if any)
5. Reinstall the official Qt5 library package
6. Reboot

Let me know if this helps!

If not, you'll have to check Qt5's dependencies and reinstall them as well. To do that: `$ apt-cache depends [name of qt5 package]`
And reinstall them: `$ apt-get install --reinstall [package]`

D

Comment: Unortunately, removing all Qt5 libraries forcibly and then reinstalling them from scratch did not help. I can't even imagine how long it will take to reinstall all the dependencies as there are thousands and thousands of them... There is about 100 Qt5 packages.

Comment: I tried to reinstall also dependencies of libqt5core5a and libqt5gui5 (the last one actually contains xcb plugin), and still getting the same error. There is something else, which I am missing... Any extra ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, if this is still not fixed here's my advice: stop spending time on trying to find a solution. Backup your data (including app data ;-) ) and configurations, reinstall Ubuntu, make a snapshot once you're done reinstalling everything and learn from your mistakes :-)

Comment: Sorry, @Danyright. I have left a comment under original message rather than here, because it was related to the alternative solution rather than yours. Probably without your solution though that one would not work, I do not know. Now it is very hard to say, but now it seems that it is all working just fine.

Comment: Ok, glad to know you fixed it. Don't hesitate to upvote the answers that helped you and post your solution as official answer ;-)